# How can I get MIN and MAX values for dimension members in a set that uses NON EMPTY

Tags: mdx

I have a problem where I need to get the high and low values for a set from the dimension members (not the measures) for a specific intersection (one customer and time period). We need to reference these for report parameters downstream.  I can only find examples for pulling the min and max measures.  I need the actual dimension values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the KEY0 is a numerical value, you could do something like :

```
select

  topCount( [Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].members, 1, [Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].currentMember.properties( 'KEY0', TYPED ) )      
  + bottomCount( [Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].members, 1, [Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].currentMember.properties( 'KEY0', TYPED ) ) 

  on 0 

from [Sales]
```

Otherwise any other numerical property would be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I think we are getting close.  I got the following error:  Query (1, 46) The 'Rent Range' dimension contains more than one hierarchy, therefore the hierarchy must be explicitly specified.

Comment: Any ideas?  I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Add the name of the hierarchy you want to use : [Rent Range].[hierarchy-name].[Rent Range Floor]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement, see if the following helps you out.

```
SELECT   TOPCOUNT(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS([Hit Time].[Date], 1, LEAVES)),1) ON 0  
FROM  [cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the max you case use [TopCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792)(your set, 1, your measure)

For the min you case use [BottomCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144864)(your set, 1, your measure)

Comment: That worked to get the topcount for apps (the measure), but I am looking for the MAX value for the dimension (rent range):
SELECT {[Measures].[Apps]} ON COLUMNS,
topcount([Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].Members, 1, [Measures].[Apps]) ON ROWS


FROM [CreditApplication] 

where {[Time].[Date].&[2011-01-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2012-06-01T00:00:00]}

Comment: The following expression will return the rent range that has the highest value:
TopcCount([Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].Members, 1, [Rent Range].CurrentMember.MemberValue)

Does this mdx return what you need:
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rent range value] AS [Rent Range].CurrentMember.MemberValue
SELECT {[Measures].[Rent range value]} ON COLUMNS,
TopCount([Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].Members, 1, [Measures].[Rent range value]) ON ROWS
FROM [CreditApplication] where {[Time].[Date].&[2011-01-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2012-06-01T00:00:00]}

Comment: Getting closer - I just need this to return values for the rent range where my measure has non empty values now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1486179 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rent range value] AS [Rent Range].CurrentMember.MemberValue SELECT {[Measures].[Rent range value]} ON COLUMNS, TopCount(NonEmpty([Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].Members, [Measures].[Rent range value]), 1, [Measures].[Rent range value]) ON ROWS FROM [CreditApplication] where {[Time].[Date].&[2011-01-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2012-06-01T00:00:00]}

Do you still want the TopCount?

Comment: WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rent range value] AS [Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].CurrentMember.MemberValue

SELECT non empty [Measures].[Rent range value] ON COLUMNS, 

{TopCount(NonEmpty([Rent Range].[Rent Range Floor].Children, [Measures].[Rent range value]), 1, [Measures].[Rent range value])}

ON ROWS

FROM [CreditApplication] 

where ({[Time].[Date].&[2011-01-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Date].&[2012-06-01T00:00:00]},[OrgUnit].[OrgUnit].&[2])

Comment: We used the above but can't find a way to tuple it with the measure we want to only get the top value where there are non empty values.  It brings back values for the dim and not the tuple.  Ideas?

Comment: @user1486179 are you talking about ``[Measures].[Rent range value]`` or another measure? I do not understand if you want to change how the tuples are ordered/filtred on the rows or if you want to display another measure in the result.